# Does it harm if I use TensorFlow without an isolated python environment?

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed TensorFlow using [Anaconda Installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation).

During the installation, after sourcing into the 'tensorflow' environment (create by *conda*), I used **pip in my anaconda**(i.e. `$HOME/anaconda/bin/pip3`) instead of **pip or pip3 in the tensorflow environment**(i.e. `$HOME/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/bin/pip`) to install TensorFlow.

When I test my installation, I find that I can still `import tensorflow` even if I am not in the 'tensorflow' environment(after `source deactivate`). So I think I am actually using tensorflow without an isolated python environment. Does it harm?

Answer (score 0):

If it works well for you, that's good, but in general this isn't an approach we test extensively or support, so your mileage may vary!

Comment: I recently figure out that what I have done has nothing to do with virtual python environment. I just installed tensorflow in a way what [Pip Installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) suggests.